# Null pointer exception while accessing service inside spark worker

Tags: java, apache-spark

Getting a NullPointerException thrown by the worker when it tries to access a SparkContext object that's present on the driver but worker is throwing null.

However, working fine the local but failing on the cluster.

Any help???

Comment: Without the logs and stacktrace, it'll be impossible to help.
Look at the logs and see where it's being thrown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)